# sizeof operator in conjunction with variable-length array as function arguments

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, sizeof, variable-length-array

According to GNU's documentation on [Arrays of Variable Length](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), one can use the sizeof operator for determining the size of a variable length array that was passed into a function:

> You can also use variable-length arrays as arguments to functions:
>
> ```
> struct entry
> tester (int len, char data[len][len])
> {
>   /* … */
> }
> ```
>
> The length of an array is computed once when the storage is allocated and is remembered for the scope of the array in case you access it with `sizeof`.

However, when trying this example with the complete code example below, the `sizeof` operator returns the size of the pointer, **not** the size of the allocated vla, as is expected based on the GNU snippet above.

I understand that passing arrays in C is akin to passing a pointer to the first element of the array, but since we're specifying the size in this case in the function signature, I would expect the behavior to mimic when using `sizeof` in the scope of where the array is declared.

I also realize I could use the `len` argument to figure out the size; but as a matter of convenience and understanding the GNU implementation I still think this is an interesting (if not important) question.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can provide insight into this!

```
// file: vla.c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int len, char data[len][len]) {
  printf("sizeof \"foo\" data: %lu\n", sizeof(data));
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  char data[argc][argc];
  printf("sizeof \"main\" data: %lu\n", sizeof(data));
  foo(argc, data);
}
```

**Compiled using:**

```
gcc vla.c -o vla -std=c11
```

**Called using:**

```
./vla 2 3 4 5
```

**Output:**

```
sizeof "main" data: 25
sizeof "foo" data: 8
```

**Analysis:**

The size of the `main` `data` makes sense; `argc` is 5, therefore it's a (5 * 5 = 25) byte 2D array.

The size of the `foo` `data` was expected to also be 25, but is instead the size of the pointer.  Seemingly the compiler is not using the fact that it knows the size of `data` within `foo` since it's part of the function signature.

Comment: I suspect you'll find that the normal rules apply to function arguments (you get the size of a pointer).  What the text you quote is mainly referring to is arrays defined inside a function (you can't define variable size arrays at global scope).  Having said that, the manual reference definitely implies that what you're doing should work.

Comment: Aside: Better to use `"%zu"` with `size_t` --> `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(...));`

Comment: After some frenzied cogitation, I think that storage isn't allocated when you call a function. I think the paragraph after the sample code is a non sequitur.  But it isn't obvious from what the manual says.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I agree with that assessment.  Also thanks for the formatting fixes, much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An argument declared `char data[len][len]` is really `char (*data)[len]`, a pointer to a VLA. There is no such thing as an actual array argument, and the first `len` in the declaration is meaningless. If you use `sizeof *data`, you will get back `len` though, since the pointed-to type is variably modified.

If you want both `len`s to be meaningful, you can pass a pointer-to-whole-array type rather than a pointer-to-first-element, declaring the argument `char (*data)[len][len]`. Now `sizeof *data` is `len*len`. But you'll need to use `(*data)[i][j]` to access it. You'll also need to use the `&` operator when calling the function:

```
int l = 42;
char array[l][l];
foo(l, &array);
```

Comment: It should be noted [the page OP refers to](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) is poorly written. It says “You can also use variable-lenth arrays as arguments to functions” and gives the example of an argument declared `char data[len][len]`. This might be technically correct, as an array can be “used” as an argument for this function, but it is nonetheless converted to a pointer, and the wording is misleading, perhaps suggesting GCC is supporting some C expansion or deviation…

Comment: … The type `char data[len][len]` is likely intended to make the point that the second dimension is variable-length. The wording should likely have said that variable-length arrays may be used as parts of types passed to functions, using an example such as `char (*data)[len]`.